# team foundation server 2010 installation from DVD - I get agent installation instead!

Tags: team-foundation-server

GRRRRRRRRRRRR!(#Y%)@#!!

They bragged they now have a very easy installation!

I don't get it. I entered the MSDN "Disk 5000: Developer Tools" DVD, opened default.htm, clicked on the "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2010" link.

The VSTFS2010 folder open. I click autorun.exe.  And then I get "Microsoft Visual Studio **Agents** 2010 Setup".

I don't get it. Why "agents"? I wanted to instal a server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

?
Anyhow, downloaded en_visual_studio_team_foundation_server_2010_x86_x64_dvd_559671.iso from MSDN, and made it work.